# MKL: failed to observe the effect of threading

Tags: multithreading, openmp, intel-mkl

I'd like to call cblas_drot at some point of my code, which is not in a parallel region. Then I get confused that the execution time for this call is basically the same in single thread mode and 24-thread. I set the number of threads by mkl_set_num_threads() before the function call. Anyone has any idea of what might happened?

The cpu is 2*Xeon E5 2620v3 and OS is Ubuntu 16.04.2.

Comment: The BLAS and LAPACK libraries supplied with linux distros are single threaded.  Proprietary performance library builds such as Intel MKL and AMD may have built-in OpenMP threading of appropriate functions, but not all functions in the library. Default value of mkl_set_num_threads is number of physical cores.

Comment: MKL ?rot functions are listed as threaded, but it seems unlikely that they would scale to 24 threads even if you have 24 physical cores and a problem size which is optimal for scaling.  ark.intel.com indicates you would have 6 cores per cpu so it seems that setting more than 12 threads would be counter-productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are saturating the memory bandwidth. The computational intensity of that function is very low and the performances are mostly dictated by the timings of memory accesses. Actually the scalability results strongly depend on the increments incX and incY. Assuming N = 10000000, I found that (CPU E5-2670):

```
N threads |  time for incX=incY=1  | time for incX=incY=32
1         |  0.026271              |  1.243775
2         |  0.020599              |  0.555945
4         |  0.017871              |  0.301370
8         |  0.021367              |  0.152756
16        |  0.021729              |  0.175500
```

That shows that the speed-up is decent up to 8 threads (and still there at 16 threads) when incX/Y is different from 1. When incX/Y=1, a very well optimized version of the function (with significant usage of AVX functions) uses the major part of the available memory bandwidth making the results of the OpenMP parallelization very poor. I am just guessing what is happening: to confirm that, you might consider the usage of a low-level profiler.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the meaning of incX and incY, which I set to be 0 in my program, and indeed when incX/Y =1 the performance is observed to be desirable. But I'm still wondering what's the exact meaning of incX/Y? Looks like it has something to do with filling the vector registers but I can't find any clue in available materials.

Comment: incX/Y are the strides between consecutive items of arrays which have to be modified according to the operator (rotation in this case). Normally incX/Y=1 but larger values can be useful when, e.g., you want to work on columns of arrays representing matrices. Check the basic netlib implementation to clarify: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/drot.f.html